# Spring-Boot - Only some variables of an object are binding

Tags: java, ajax, spring-boot, binding

I am trying make a AJAX post request to my spring boot application. The Javascript seems to be working fine as all value are populated in the POST request - however when the Commonage object hits the Java class we can only see that 3 out of 11 fields have come through with a value. Output of this program is:

`null
0.0
0.0
0
0
null
null
null
TOWNLAND
Not Set
This is the comment`

JAVASCRIPT

```
var commonage_id = document.getElementById("commonage_id").value;
var townland = document.getElementById("edit_townland").value;
var gross_area = parseFloat(document.getElementById("edit_gross_area").value);
var max_elig = parseFloat(document.getElementById("edit_max_elig").value);
    var min_stock = parseFloat(document.getElementById("edit_min_stock").value);
    var max_stock = parseFloat(document.getElementById("edit_max_stock").value);
    var start_date = document.getElementById("edit_start_date").value;
    var end_date = document.getElementById("edit_end_date").value;
    var owner_share = document.getElementById("edit_owner_share").value;
    var type = document.getElementById("typeSelect").value;
    var comment = document.getElementById("comment").value;


    var commonage = {
            commonage_id,
            gross_area,
            max_elig,
            min_stock,
            max_stock,
            start_date,
            end_date,
            owner_share,
            type, 
            townland,
            comment
    }

    $.ajax({
          url:"UpdateCommonage",
          type:"POST",
          data: JSON.stringify(commonage),
          contentType:"application/json; charset=utf-8",
          dataType:"json",
          success: function(){
                alert("success");
          }
        })`
```

COMMONAGE CLASS

```
import java.util.Date;

public class Commonage {

private String commonageIdentifier;
private double grossArea;
private double maxEligibleArea;
private int minStock;
private int maxStock;
private Date startDate;
private Date endDate;
private String ownerShare;
private String type;
private String townland;
private String comment;

public Commonage() {

}

public Commonage(String commonageIdentifier, double grossArea, double maxEligibleArea, int minStock,
        int maxStock, Date startDate, Date endDate, String ownerShare, String type, String townland, String comment) {
    this.commonageIdentifier = commonageIdentifier;
    this.grossArea = grossArea;
    this.maxEligibleArea = maxEligibleArea;
    this.minStock = minStock;
    this.maxStock = maxStock;
    this.startDate = startDate;
    this.endDate = endDate;
    this.ownerShare = ownerShare;
    this.type = type;
    this.townland = townland;
    this.comment = comment;
}

public String getCommonageIdentifier() {
    return commonageIdentifier;
}

public void setCommonageIdentifier(String commonageIdentifier) {
    this.commonageIdentifier = commonageIdentifier;
}

public double getGrossArea() {
    return grossArea;
}

public void setGrossArea(double grossArea) {
    this.grossArea = grossArea;
}

public double getMaxEligibleArea() {
    return maxEligibleArea;
}

public void setMaxEligibleArea(double maxEligibleArea) {
    this.maxEligibleArea = maxEligibleArea;
}

public int getMinStock() {
    return minStock;
}

public void setMinStock(int minStock) {
    this.minStock = minStock;
}

public int getMaxStock() {
    return maxStock;
}

public void setMaxStock(int maxStock) {
    this.maxStock = maxStock;
}

public Date getStartDate() {
    return startDate;
}

public void setStartDate(Date startDate) {
    this.startDate = startDate;
}

public Date getEndDate() {
    return endDate;
}

public void setEndDate(Date endDate) {
    this.endDate = endDate;
}

public String getOwnerShare() {
    return ownerShare;
}

public void setOwnerShare(String ownerShare) {
    this.ownerShare = ownerShare;
}

public String getType() {
    return type;
}

public void setType(String type) {
    this.type = type;
}

public String getTownland() {
    return townland;
}

public void setTownland(String townland) {
    this.townland = townland;
}

public String getComment() {
    return comment;
}

public void setComment(String comment) {
    this.comment = comment;
}
```

}

CONTROLLER METHOD

```
@RequestMapping("UpdateCommonage")
@ResponseBody
public boolean updateCommonage(@RequestBody Commonage commonage) {

    System.out.println(commonage.getCommonageIdentifier());
    System.out.println(commonage.getGrossArea());
    System.out.println(commonage.getMaxEligibleArea());
    System.out.println(commonage.getMaxStock());
    System.out.println(commonage.getMinStock());
    System.out.println(commonage.getStartDate());
    System.out.println(commonage.getEndDate());
    System.out.println(commonage.getOwnerShare());
    System.out.println(commonage.getTownland());
    System.out.println(commonage.getType());
    System.out.println(commonage.getComment());

    return false;
}
```

Comment: Have you checked what is actually sent in your ajax request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default, Jackson (the JSON (de)serializer used in Spring Boot) will look for the property names in the JSON that match exactly with the property names on your Java class.

There are two options. The recommended and best practice would be to not use the snake case variable names in your JavaScript. Typically JavaScript variable names are written in camel case. So, instead of what you have above, you would change the body of the request to be:

```
var commonage = {
    commonageIdentifier,
    grossArea,
    maxEligibleArea,
    minStock,
    maxStock,
    startDate,
    endDate,
    ownerShare,
    type, 
    townland,
    comment
}
```

Notice how the only properties that seemed to map properly were the ones that were one word.

The other less desirable option is to tell Jackson the property name to look for on the JSON using the `@JsonProperty` annotation on your Java class, like so:

```
public class Commonage {

    @JsonProperty("commonage_id")
    private String commonageIdentifier;

    @JsonProperty("gross_area")
    private double grossArea;

    @JsonProperty("max_elig")
    private double maxEligibleArea;

    @JsonProperty("min_stock")
    private int minStock;

    @JsonProperty("max_stock")
    private int maxStock;

    @JsonProperty("start_date")
    private Date startDate;

    @JsonProperty("end_date")
    private Date endDate;

    @JsonProperty("owner_share")
    private String ownerShare;

    @JsonProperty("type")
    private String type;

    @JsonProperty("townland")
    private String townland;

    @JsonProperty("comment")
    private String comment;
}
```